# Imprimir contenido HTML desde PHP a variable Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Como dice en el título, no logro hacer lo siguiente:

```
 <html>
 ......

 <script>
     var texto = " <?php echo $html; ?> ";
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

No se como hacer para que el conteido html que está en la variable PHP, se cargue en la variable de javascript. Generar un error a nivel en JS.

Supongo que debe ser porque a lo mejor entra en conflicto algunas de estas posibles expresiones al tratar de imprimirlo. var texto = "`<html><p class = "class_one"></p></html>`"; ya con ese ejemplo, deberia dar un problema en el cliente, pero no se como lograr hacer esa asignación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias a todos por su ayuda, lo he resulto con esto:

```
var texto = <?php echo json_encode($articuloConsulta['contenido']); ?>;
```

Tomado de:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines

Answer (score 1):

Primero tienes que asegurarte de que las comillas no interfieran con el código de JavaScript, iniciando y terminando la cadena con la comilla simple:

```
var texto = ' <?php echo $html; ?> ';
```

A continuación, puedes apoyarte de un reemplazo por expresión regular para eliminar saltos de línea de tu cadena html, para que no falle la asignación de la variable.

```
preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $html);
```

Básado en tu código, el ejemplo completo sería el siguiente:

```
 <html>
 ......

 <script>
     var texto = '<?php echo preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $html); ?>';
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pasa por las comillas, lo que tienes que hacer es:

```
 <html>
 ......

 <script>
     var texto = ' <?php echo $html; ?> ';
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Gracias, por la ayuda. Pero la variable $html, es algo extensa, contiene muchos caracteres, y eso incluye también las comillas simples.

Answer (score 0):

Identifica todos aquellos caracteres que pueden estr "rompiendo" tu dato que se mostrara; es decir busca y elimina por ejemplo:

- saltode linea, retorno de carro (como ya te comento Francisco Javier Escoppinichi ) `con preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $html);`
- Otros caracteres que requieren `\`
- Al resultate del punto anterior aplicarle [htmlentities();](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php)

Ejemplo:

```
<script>
 var texto = '<?php 
 $html=preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $html); 
 // Ejemplo de algunos que requieren "\"
 $html=str_replace("\"", "\\"", $html); 
 $html=str_replace("'", "\\'", $html); 
 $html=str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $html); 

 $html=preg_htmlentities($html);

 echo $html;
?>';
</script>
```